# Induced Measure Integral

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, change-of-variable

In my text, I have the following change of variables formulas:

> A function $f: \Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is integrable with respect to the induced measure $\mu (T^{-1})$ iff $f(T)$ is integrable with respect to $\mu$.
>
> In this case, it holds that $$ \int_{\Omega}f(T(\omega))\mu(d \omega) = \int_{\Omega_{1}} f(\omega_{1})\mu(T^{-1}) (d \omega_{1}) $$ $$\int_{A}f(T(\omega))\mu(d \omega) = \int_{T(A)}f(\omega_{1})\mu(T^{-1}(A_{1}))(d\omega_{1}),\,\text{for any}\,A_{1} \in \mathcal{F}_{1}\,\,\,\,\,(*) $$
>   (where $\mathcal{F}_{1}$ is a $\sigma$-field). ($A \in \mathcal{F})$

Now, when $T(\omega) = \varphi(\omega) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_{i}I_{A_{i}}(\omega)$ and $f(x) = x^{2}$, I have to verify that $(*)$ holds.

Plugging in everything that I know into $(*)$, I have for the LHS: $$\int_{A_{1}}\left[ \varphi(\omega)\right]^{2}\mu(d \omega) = \int_{A_{1}} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_{i} I_{A_{i}}(\omega)\right]^{2} \mu(d \omega).$$

For the RHS, I have that $$\int_{\varphi(A_{1})}  \omega_{1}^{2}\mu \left( \varphi^{-1}(A _{1})\right)d(\omega_{1}) = \int_{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_{i}I_{A_{i}} (A_{1})} \omega_{1}^2 \mu(\varphi^{-1}(A_{1}))d(\omega_{1})$$. And since it seems to me that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_{i}I_{A_{i}}(A_{1}) = x_{1}$, I would imagine that this last integral would equal $$  = \int_{x_{1}}\omega_{1}^2 \mu(\varphi^{-1}(A_{1}))d(\omega_{1})$$

Now, then, my goal is to show that $$  \int_{A_{1}} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_{i} I_{A_{i}}(\omega)\right]^{2} \mu(d \omega) = \int_{x_{1}}\omega_{1}^2 \mu(\varphi^{-1}(A_{1}))d(\omega_{1}) $$

But, how do I do that? For one thing, what is the preimage under $\varphi$ of $A_{1}$? And then, what is its $\mu-$measure? Also, how do I get the sets that we're integrating over to be the same thing?

I am very stuck and really need help finishing this proof. I thank you ahead of time for your time and patience!

Comment: It would help if you could write down more details.  $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$? What is $\Omega_1$? and $\mu_1$? Are the sets $A_i$ disjoint? What are $x_i$?

Comment: @Gio67 sorry about that.We have two measurable spaces $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ and $(\Omega_{1}, \mathcal{F}_{1})$, with a measurable mapping $T:\Omega \mapsto \Omega_{1}$. Also, $(\Omega_{1},\mathcal{F}_{1})  = (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}) $. $\mu$ is the measure for the space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$, but there is no $\mu_{1}$ for  $(\Omega_{1}, \mathcal{F}_{1})$. Rather, on that space, we have the induced measure $\mu(T^{-1})$ given by $\mu(T^{-1}(A_{1}) \equiv \mu(T^{-1}(A_{1}))$ for any $A_{1} \in \mathcal{F}_{1}$.

Comment: @Gio67 I also just fixed the question a little.

Comment: I guess the second equation should be $\int_{A_{1}}f(T(\omega))\mu(d \omega) = \int_{T(A_{1})}f(\omega_{1})(\mu(T^{-1}))(d\mu_{1}),\,\text{for any}\,A_{1} \in \mathcal{F}$

Comment: @novavita I was thinking not because if you notice the equation above has $\Omega$ on the first integral and $T(\Omega)$ on the second integral, but $A_{1} \notin \Omega$, it's in $\Omega_{1}$, which here is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I am sorry but $ \int_{\Omega_{1}} f(\omega_{1})\mu(T^{-1}) (d \mu_{1})$ and $ \int_{T(A)}f(\omega_{1})\mu(T^{-1}(A_{1}))(d\mu_{1}),\,$ make no sense. What is $\omega_1$ and $\mu_1$? I agree with nova vita.

Comment: @ALannister but then I am confused about the relationship between $\mu_1$ and $\mu$: have you defined $\mu_1$ yet? if not, then the first equation should be $\int_{\Omega}f(T(\omega))\mu(d \omega) = \int_{\Omega_{1}} f(\omega_{1})\mu(T^{-1}) (d \omega_{1})$ I suppose.

Comment: @Gio67 it doesn't say $d \mu_{1}$, it says $d \omega_{1}$ There is no $\mu_{1}$ here at all.  The $\omega_{1}$ is just a sample point from $\mathbb{R}$. I realized I had a $\mu_{1}$ in there - it was a typo. I've fixed it.

Comment: nova vita is right. The RHS should be $ \int_{\Omega_{1}} f(\omega_{1})\mu(T^{-1}) (d \omega_{1})$. Also are the sets $A_i$ disjoint?

Comment: @Gio67 yes he is. I just fixed it. And they are disjoint.

Comment: and one more question... what is the relationship between $A_1$ and $A$? Is $A_1=TA$?

Comment: @novavita well, $T(A)$ is the image of $A$ under the transformation $T$ which here is $\sigma(\omega) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_{i}I_{A_{i}}(\omega)$. So, I guess $T(A) = \sigma(A) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_{i}I_{A_{i}}(A)$?

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I still think  the second equation is not correct since $\mu(T^{-1})$ is a measure, when integrating w.r.t. a measure, you should write $\int_{T(A)}f(\omega_{1})(\mu(T^{-1}))(d\omega_{1})$

Comment: and all in all, I have to say your problem seems to come from notational abuse... for example, $\int_{A_{1}}\left[ \varphi(\omega)\right]^{2}\mu(d \omega) = \int_{A_{1}} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_{i} I_{A_{i}}(\omega)\right]^{2} \mu(d \omega)$ you should write $A$ instead of $A_1$, and in $= \int_{x_{1}}\omega_{1}^2 \mu(\varphi^{-1}(A_{1}))d(\omega_{1})$ you should write $\{x_1\}$ instead of $x_1$. Then $(\mu (T^{-1})(\{x_1\})$ can be defined @ALannister

Comment: @novavita how will defining $(\mu(T^{-1})(\{x_{1} \})$ help me?

Comment: @novavita I just want to get the integral on the RHS to look like how Gio67 got the left hand side to look in his answer below, and I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: @ALannister $(\mu(T^{-1})(\{x_{_i} \})=x_i^2\mu(A_i)$, according to your definition.

Comment: @novavita so how does this all fit together? I think Gio's abandoned me. From the way he says things, I'm not even sure anymore if I should have $x_{1}$ as the set we're integrating over on the second integral!

Comment: @novavita what is $(\mu (T^{-1}) (A)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably get hold of another text. The formula $(*)$ does not make sense in general. Let me change the notation a bit and use indexes 1 and 2 for the respective spaces. 
Let $$T:(\Omega_1,{\cal B}_1) \rightarrow (\Omega_2,{\cal B}_2)$$ be a measurable map between spaces equipped with $\sigma$-algebras. By definition for any $A_2\in {\cal B}_2$ the set $T^{-1} A_2 \in {\cal B}_1$ is thus measurable. But nothing assures that $A_1\in {\cal B}_1$ implies $TA_1\in {\cal B}_2$. If e.g. $\Omega_1=\Omega_2$ but ${\cal B}_2 \subsetneq {\cal B}_1$ (strict subset), then the identity map is measurable but its inverse (also the
 identity) is not!

When $\mu_1$ is a measure on $(\Omega_1,{\cal B}_1)$ you get the unique push-forward measure by declaring:
 $$ \mu_2 (A_2) = \mu_1 (T^{-1} A_2) = \mu_1 \circ T^{-1} (A_2) ,
 \;\;\; A_2\in {\cal B}_2$$
This may be written in terms if integrals (using indicator functions) as:
 $$ \int_{\Omega_2} {\bf 1}_{A_2} \;d\mu_2 = 
\int_{\Omega_1} {\bf 1}_{T^{-1}A_2} \;d\mu_1= \int_{\Omega_1}
   {\bf 1}_{A_2} \circ T \; d\mu_1,$$
where I used that $x\in T^{-1} A_2$ iff 
$Tx \in A_2$. Taking linear combinations you get for a step function $f:\Omega_2\rightarrow {\Bbb R}$
$$ \int_{\Omega_2} f \;d\mu_2 = 
 \int_{\Omega_1}
   f \circ T \; d\mu_1.$$
Passing through Lebesgue monotone convergence for positive step functions you get the result for any integrable function $f\in L^1(\mu_2)$. If you first restrict your measure to a set $\Lambda_2\in {\cal B}_2$ then you get first:
 $$ \int_{\Lambda_2} {\bf 1}_{A_2} \;d\mu_2 = 
\int_{T^{-1}\Lambda_2} {\bf 1}_{T^{-1}A_2} \;d\mu_1= \int_{T^{-1}\Lambda_2}
   {\bf 1}_{A_2} \circ T \; d\mu_1$$
and then for any integrable $f$ you get (as a theorem) the correct version of $(*)$:
$$ \int_{\Lambda_2} f \;d\mu_2 = 
 \int_{T^{-1}\Lambda_2}
   f \circ T \; d\mu_1.$$

In the example it is possible to calculate the push-forward measure but you would actually never do so, as in general it is very complicated. Instead simply use the above theorem.
It does, however, become easy  when the measurable sets in your sum are disjoint. So let us assume this. Again the notation is not strikingly optimal when using $A_i$ for several purposes, so let us write:
  $$ \phi = \sum_i x_i {\bf 1}_{E_i} $$
with the countable family $(E_i)_{i\geq 1}$ being a disjoint family. Then
 $$ \mu_2(A) = \mu_1(T^{-1} A) = \sum_{i: x_i\in A} \mu_1(E_i)$$
The support of $\mu_2$ is in $S=\{y |\exists i : x_i=y\}$ and you get:
$$ \int_{\Lambda_2} f\;d\mu_2 = \sum_{y\in \Lambda_2} 
  y^2 \mu_2(\{y\}) = \sum_{i: x_i\in \Lambda_2}
 x_i^2 \mu_1(E_i) = 
  \int_{T^{-1} \Lambda_2} (T(\omega))^2 d\mu_1(\omega)$$

Comment: this was such an incredible answer and you really helped me so much! Would it be possible for you to please help me with this question as well? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520147/induced-distribution-measure-and-induced-distribution-function-where-original-r There is a 100 point bounty on it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think that the second equality may work only for injective mapping $T$. Here 
$\mu\circ T^{-1}$ is a discrete measure which is concentrated on $\{x_i\}$, i.e. $\mu\circ T^{-1}(B)=\sum_{x_i\in B}\mu(A_i)$ (assuming that the sets $A_i$ are disjoint and $\bigcup_{i}A_i=\Omega$). So

$$
\int x^21_{T(A)}(\mu\circ T^{-1})(dx)=\sum_{x_i\in T(A)} x_i^2\mu(A_i)\ge\sum x_i^2\mu(A\cap A_i)
$$

---

Here is a simple example. Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\Omega=\mathbb{R}_{+}$. Take $T(\omega)=\lfloor \omega\rfloor$. Then $\mu\circ T^{-1}$ is the counting measure on $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$.

If $A=(1,3/2)$, then $\int_A \lfloor \omega\rfloor^2d\omega=0.5$. But $T(A)=\{1\}$ so that the second integral equals $1$.

Comment: do you mean "injective"? Also, are you saying you only get equality in the last part where you have  $\geq$ if $T$ is injective? I thought it order for it to have an inverse, it would need to be injective anyway...

Comment: "I thought it order for it to have an inverse, it would need to be injective anyway". $T$ need not be invertible to define the image measure $\mu\circ T^{-1}$. $T^{-1}(B)$ is just the inverse image of $B$ under $T$...

Answer (score 1):

sorry, I was wrong. as  d.k.o. said, T should be injective. here is the corrected version.

---

ok let me expand my comments. I insists that
$$
\int_{A}f(T(\omega))\mu(d \omega) = \int_{T(A)}f(\omega_{1})(\mu(T^{-1}))(d\omega_{1}),\,\text{for any}\,A \in \sigma (T^{-1}B), \text{where}\  B\in \mathcal F_1\,\,\,\,\,(*)
$$

Let $T(\omega) = \varphi(\omega) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_{i}I_{A_{i}}(\omega)$, where $\{A_i\}$ disjoint and compose $\Omega$. Moreover let $f(x)=x^2$. For this problem, we must find a new $\sigma-$algebra to make $T^{-1}B$ well defined, I consider $T^{-1}{x_i}=A_i$, and $A\in \sigma(A_1,A_2,...)$.

Then the l.h.s. is 
$$
\int_{A}f(T(\omega))\mu(d \omega)=\int_{A}\sum_{i=1} ^{\infty}x_i^2I_{A_i} \mu(d \omega)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_i^2\mu(A\cap A_i)
$$

note that the transformation $T$ returns only countable values $x_1,x_2,...x_n,...$, when returing $x_i$, this means $A\cap A_i\neq \phi$. so the r.h.s. is
$$
\int_{T(A)}f(\omega_{1})(\mu(T^{-1}))(d\omega_{1})=\sum _{i=1}^{\infty}\int_{A}x_i^2I_{\{A\cap A_i\neq \phi\}}d\mu
$$

Comment: and then the last sum is equal to $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_{i}^{2} \mu(A \cap A_{i})$ because $\mu(A \cap (\{A\cap A_{i}) \neq \emptyset)) = \mu (A \cap A_{i})$?

Comment: yes, note that the summation in this equation is analog to integration here since the sample space of $\Omega_1$ is countable.

Comment: I'm accepting and awarding you the bounty, but could you explain what you mean by "only countable values"? Do you mean countably many values? I would think that "returning" a value means that the output of the function is that value. I think this might be a language issue for me.

Comment: sure, I say "only countable" to emphasise that the integration would not take the common continuous form, but like an infinite sum

Comment: does that say that $A$ is in the sigma algebra generated by $T^{-1}(B)$?

Comment: I figure out it is still incorrect.....like d.k.o. said $T$ should be invective. don't give me the bounty then.

Comment: I don't even know what an invective mapping is. I think it's probably fine. Don't worry about it. Anyway, I can't award the bounty for 21 hours.

Comment: and withdraw accept, sorry for that. I think he means injective.