# Expectation for a sum of Poisson random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

Let $Z = \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}X_{r}$, where $X_{r}$ is of Poisson Distribution with intensity rate $\frac{1}{r^{2}}$ for $r \geq 1$. Assume $Z$ is of some distribution (not necessarily Poisson itself).

I need to compute the expectation, $E(Z)$, and was given as a hint to use Monotone Convergence.

However, I am having a hard time setting up this problem as well as figuring out where Monotone Convergence comes into play (for example, what here is monotone)?

Since $X_{r}$ is of Poisson Distribution, we should have $E(Z) = E(\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}X_{r}) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} X_{r}\frac{e^{1/r^2} \left(\frac{1}{r^2} \right)^{k}}{k!}dX_{r}$, I think. But, I do not know how to simplify the integral on the right (or even if I have written out the expectation correctly. Then, from that point, how do I apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem?

Thanks ahead of time for your time and patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partial sums of the first $k$ terms, say $S_k$, are monotone. In particular.
$$
ES_k=\sum_{r=1}^k\frac{1}{r^2}
$$
Now let $k\to\infty$ and apply the MCT.

Comment: I like this! How do I set up the expectation integral, though? So far, you're in the running for accepting an answer. But, I still don't see how to do this one part.

Comment: @ALannister $S_k\uparrow Z\implies ES_k\uparrow EZ $.

Comment: I have a 100 point bounty on this question if you're interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456239/change-of-variable-changing-integral-from-one-measure-space-into-another

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z_n=\sum_{r=1}^n X_r$. Then
$$
\mathsf{E}Z=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{E}Z_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^n\mathsf{E}X_r=\sum_{r=1}^\infty r^{-2}=\frac{1}{6}\pi^2.
$$

Comment: what's the right way to set up the integral, though?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathsf{E}X_r$? The expectation of a Poisson r.v. with parameter $\lambda$ is $\lambda$...

Comment: no I mean $E Z$

Comment: The whole point of this exercise is that you don't need to set up any integral. All u need to do is to replace $\mathsf{E}Z$ with the limit of the expectation of partial sums...

Comment: Oh! Okay! Better :)

Comment: I have a 100 point bounty on this question if you're interested in helping: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456239/change-of-variable-changing-integral-from-one-measure-space-into-another

Answer (score 1):

**Monotone convergence theorem** Let $(X_n)_{n\ge}$ be random variables such that $X_n\ge 0$ and $X_n\le X_{n+1}$ for all $n$. Then $X_n \uparrow X$ as $n\to\infty$ a.s. and
$$
\Bbb E(X_n) \uparrow \Bbb E(X)\quad \text{as } n\to\infty.
$$

Let $X_r$ be Poisson random variables with parameter $\frac{1}{r^2}$. Let
$Z_n = X_1 +\cdots + X_n$ and $Z=\sum_{r=1}^\infty X_r$ so we have $Z_n \uparrow Z$ a.s. and
$$
\Bbb E(Z_n)=\sum_{r=1}^n\Bbb E(X_r)=\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r^2}\to\Bbb E(Z)=\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{1}{r^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$

Comment: don't know if you're interested, but I have a 100-point bounty on this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456239/change-of-variable-changing-integral-from-one-measure-space-into-another