# Calculate the difference around a rectangle (measure in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I need to calculate $\Delta_{(a,b]}F$ for $\mathbf{a}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}$, $\mathbf{b}=\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$ and the bivariate Marshall-Olkin exponential distribution function $$ F(x,y) = 1 - e^{-x}-e^{-2y}+e^{-x-2y - \max \{x ,y \}} $$
for $x,y \geq 0$.

**First, a little Background**:

- For two points $a,b$ of $\mathbb{R}^{k}$, the set $$V((a,b]) \equiv \{ (c_{1},\cdots , c_{k} ) : c_{i} = a_{i}\,\text{or}\, c_{i}=b_{i},\,i=1,\cdots ,k \} $$ comprises the $2^{k}$ **vertices of the (generalized) rectangle** $(a,b]$
- Denote the **sign number** of the vertex of the rectangle $(a,b]$ by $$\displaystyle sgn_{(a,b]}(x) = (-1)^{\sum_{i=1}^{k}I_{(x_{i}=a_{i})}},$$ for $x \in V((a,b])$
- For a componentwise right-continuous and non-decreasing function $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^{k}$, the **difference around a rectangle** $(a,b]$ $$\Delta_{(a,b]}F = \sum_{x \in V((a,b])} sgn_{(a,b]}(x)F(x)$$
- If a componentwise right-continuous and non-decreasing function $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ has nonnegative difference around any rectangle; i.e., $\Delta_{(a,b]}F\geq 0$ for any points $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$, then a measure $\mu$ is uniquely defined through $$\mu((\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]) \equiv \Delta_{(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]}F, $$ for any points $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$.
- Conversely, given a measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb{R}^{k}, \mathcal{B}^{k})$, a componentwise right-continuous and non-decreasing function $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ is defined by $$F(x) \equiv \mu((-\infty, x]), $$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$.

**I have no examples of how this is done, and it does not seem the formulas I have work for a function $F$ of two variables, although all the definitions mention $\mathbb{R}^{k}$, so that must include the case where $k=2$. However, I cannot see how to actually plug everything in to the formula and use it. Could somebody please help me?**

Thank you ahead of time for your help and your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think any probability textbook would contain the following formula (e.g. Ash, R. B., & Doleans-Dade, C. (2000). Probability and measure theory. Academic Press. page 27-28), but I am not sure whether you are allowed to apply it:
$$
\mu ((a,b])=\Delta_{(a,b]}F=F(b_1,b_2)-F(a_1,b_2)-F(b_1,a_2)+F(a_1,a_2)
$$
where in your example $F$ is given and 
$[a_1,a_2]=[1,1]$,$[b_1,b_2]=[2,3]$.

Comment: well, mine doesn't, but what is this formula called?

Comment: not sure how to tag you

Comment: I don't know whether it has a name...just simple set operations. @ALannister

Comment: I have a 100 point bounty on this question if you're able to help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456239/change-of-variable-changing-integral-from-one-measure-space-into-another